# How to interpret which is the troubled one?

Tags: vocabulary, learning

Only by this Healine:

"In “Infinity Pool,” the latest film by Brandon Cronenberg, a troubled writer’s vacation to an idyllic island resort turns into a surreal, existential nightmare."

Can I know only by this text and no further context either the writer is troubled or the writer’s vacation is the troubled one?

Comment: it's the ***writer*** who is "troubled" in your example. If it was the ***vacation***, that would be ***a writer's troubled vacation*** (the vacation was "troubled" in some way, which *may* have also troubled the vacationing writer himself, but that's a matter of logic, not language).

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that was very clarifying. I thought maybe "writer’s vacation" could be seen as a unit, so it would be troubled (writer’s vacation ) get it?

Comment: Your point is a good one. I'm sure there are contexts where the two different parsings **Adjective1  [Adjective2 noun]** and **[Adjective1  Adjective2] noun** both make sense, but I couldn't think of any good examples to illustrate that when I commented. (If I *had* been able to think of some good examples I might have posted an Answer myself! :) In your *exact* case, though, "a troubled vacation" is extremely unlikely in the real world, compared to "a troubled writer".

Answer (score 1):

The adjective modifies the noun it's directly in front of. You cannot put an adjective there if it's supposed to modify *vacation*; it must go in front of the noun it's modifying:

> a troubled writer’s (long) vacation

Aside from that, in this context it wouldn't fit with how the vacation is being described. The vacation seemed perfect at the start but it becomes a nightmare.

Comment: ♦, "Aside from that, in this context it wouldn't fit with how the vacation is being described. The vacation seemed perfect at the start but it becomes a nightmare." if the vacation  ended in nightmare so it could be described as troubled, right? so it fits how vacation is being describled, agree?

Comment: @BentoUna It's a style thing. I read the sentence as being structured to show the timeline of events: perfect start to the vacation, nightmare ending. If you reveal the twist (that it ended in disaster) at the beginning of the sentence, it can't be a twist.

Comment: ♦, I'm not sure I get your point I mean even if it stated very well but ended in nightmare (the vacation ) so don't you think it (the vacation) could be adjectivided as troubled?